# How can I restrict login to a GCP Compute Engine instance (Linux) through Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a GCP Compute Engine instance (Linux).

I want to restrict connecting to the instance using the Cloud Console and permit connecting only using `gcloud compute ssh`.

But I can't find the solution.

Does anyone know about that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you trying to restrict only **how** users can connect to the instance, not **who** can connect? Does "*login to the instance through GCP-Console*" refers to "*SSH from the browser*" (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser)? Does "*ssh-command with CLI*" refers to `gcloud compute ssh` command **or** any `ssh` command?

Answer (score 0):

subnet-us-central1You can achieve that using firewall rules on the VPC Network used by the instance you’re trying to connect from.

Let's create an example VPC Network and a subnet;

```
gcloud compute networks create vpc-network-ssh --subnet-mode=custom

gcloud compute networks subnets create subnet-us-central1 --network=vpc-network-ssh --region=us-central1 --range=192.168.1.0/24
```

Create a Compute Engine instance using the above created subnet;

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-0 --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=f1-micro --subnet=subnet-us-central1
```

Every time you want to connect from a machine to this instance, create a firewall rule on the VPC Network created above to allow TCP traffic on port 22 with the machine in question as a source;

```
IP_ADDRESS=$(curl http:/ipinfo.io/ip)

gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-me --direction=INGRESS --priority=0 --network=vpc-network-ssh --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:22 --source-ranges=$IP_ADDRESS/32
```

Finally connect to the instance;

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-0 --zone=us-central1-c
```

And delete the firewall rule if you deem necessary;

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules delete allow-me --quiet
```

Find Cloud SDK’s gcloud reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/).

If your concerns are related to you not being the only user of the project,  then you could explore a solution in the context of [Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/).